# What is system:80 error showing while trying to copy file content?

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

I have this code:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std::filesystem;

int main() {
    std::error_code ec;
    bool hi = copy_file("hi.txt" , "sth.txt",ec);
    std::cout << ec;
    return 0;

}
```

When I compile and run this, it throws `system:80`, which according to [System Error Codes (0-499)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) is `ERROR_FILE_EXISTS`.

Why is this error thrown?

Comment: Because the destination file exists and no options are given to [`std::filesystem::copy_file`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_file)?

Comment: Because the file exists?

Comment: You can use a [copy_options](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_options) parameter to decide what happens if the target already exists (skip the copy/overwrite/compare which file is the newest). Default is to return an error.

Comment: Hint. Don't look up error codes, that's refuting the purpose of `std::error_code`. Instead: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/277a32ada03ad930

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior of [`std::filesystem::copy_file()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_file) is to fail with an error if the destination file already exists.  To avoid that, you need to call the overloaded version of the function which takes a [`std::filesystem::copy_options`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_options) parameter so you can tell it what to do with the existing destination file, eg:

[image]

```
bool hi = copy_file("hi.txt", "sth.txt", copy_options::skip_existing, ec);
```

```
bool hi = copy_file("hi.txt", "sth.txt", copy_options::overwrite_existing, ec);
```

```
bool hi = copy_file("hi.txt", "sth.txt", copy_options::update_existing, ec);
```